# How can I set the width of an element in CSS to be equal to 10% of the height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted my element to be a square. I wanted the side length of this element square to be 10% of the screen/window height. Yet, I don't know how to do that. Here's my code:

```
.Element {

width: /*How can I make the width equal to: [height: 10%]?*/;
height: 10%;
/*I wanted the element to be a square with a side length of [height: 10%].*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewport-percentage lengths to get the effect that you want.

The `vh` unit length is based on 1% of the viewport/screen height, which I think is the one you wnat.

Alternatively, the `vw` unit length is based on 1% of the viewport/screen's width.

You can pick either one, just use the same length unit for both `width` and `height`.

Finally, you could also experiment with the `vb` and `vi` length units.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

```css
.makeSquare {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="makeSquare"></div>
<p>This is a square.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  .Element {
     width: 20vw;
     height: 20vw;
    }
```